# Create a form which includes radio buttons with Zend Framework 1.12?

Tags: php, forms, zend-framework

I use the Zend Framework 1.12, and I am trying to create a form with Zend_Form like this:

```
<form action="">
<div class="bb-validator-form">
    <div class="form-question">
        Question 1?
    </div>
    <div class="form-row" >
        <input type="radio" name="form-val-q" id="yes" class="radio radio-yes"/>
        <label for="yes"><?php echo $this->tra->_('Yes'); ?></label>
    </div>

    <div class="form-row">
        <input type="radio" name="form-val-q" id="no" class="radio radio-no"/>
        <label for="no"><?php echo $this->tra->_('No'); ?></label>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" value="<?php echo $this->tra->_('Validate'); ?>"/>
</div>
```

My code in Zend Form is:

```
class Form_BB_Validator extends Zend_Form {
    public function init()
    {
        $this->setMethod(Zend_Form::METHOD_POST)
            ->setAttribs(array('id' =>'bb-Form'))
            ->addDecorator('FormElements')
            ->addDecorator('HtmlTag', array('tag' => 'div','class'=>'bb-validator-form'))
            ->addDecorator('Form');

        $this->addElement('text','question-1',array(
            'label'         => 'test',
            'decorators'=>array(array('Callback',array('callback'=>
                                                           create_function('','return "<h4> Question 1 ?</h4>";'))))
        ));

        $this->addElement('radio','checkValidation', array(
            'class'         => 'radio',
            'escape'        => false,
            'required'      => true,
            'multioptions'  => array('yes'=>'Yes', 'no'=>'No'),
            'decorators'    => array(
                                    array('FormElements',  array('HtmlTag', array('tag'=>'div','class'=>'bb-validator-form'))),
                                    array('ViewHelper',  array('Label', array('tag'=>'div','class'=>'bb-validator-form'))),
                                    )
        ));

        $this->addElement(new Zend_Form_Element_Submit('submit', array(
            'label'         => 'Valider',
            'class'         => 'btn btn-primary btn-block',
            'decorators'    => array(array('ViewHelper',  array('Label', array('tag'=>'div','class'=>'bb-validator-form'))),

            ))));
    }
}
```

The final output is:

```
<form id="bb-Form" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" action="" method="post">
<div class="bb-validator-form">
    <h4>Question 1 ?</h4>
    <dt id="checkValidation-label">&nbsp;</dt>
    <label for="checkValidation-yes">
    <input type="radio" name="checkValidation" id="checkValidation-yes" value="yes" class="radio">Oui</label>
    <br>
    <label for="checkValidation-no">
    <input type="radio" name="checkValidation" id="checkValidation-no" value="no" class="radio">Non</label>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Valider" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">
</div>
</form>
```

This is not correct. How do I create the form like first piece of code?

Answer (score 1):

You could use custom viewScript. Like this:

```
$this->setDecorators(
            array(
                array(
                    'ViewScript',
                    array(
                        'viewScript' => $viewsPath . '/form-bb-validator.phtml'
                    )
                )
            )
        );
```

In form-bb-validator.phtml you can design your html output like this:

```
<form>...
    <div>
    <?php echo $this->element->question-1; ?>
    </div>
...
</form>
```